# Check if view is visible and not obscured by other views?

Tags: android, android-layout

Putting Espresso aside, with just a View instance available, is there a way to test if it is visible to the user and is not obscured by anything else?

`view.getGlobalVisibleRect(Rect())` will return true if view is visible within target rectangle.

`view.visibility` in my case is Visible, but there is another view on the top of it in the layout.

`view.isShown` somehow delivers `true` even if there is another view obscuring on the top.

Any way to know if view is actually visible to the user?

Comment: if(view.getVisibilty== View.VISIBLE){

}

Comment: You can try to get coordinates of the widget and compare it with other widgets using `getDrawingRect`